# User is undefined on the context.switchToHttp().getRequest() nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, nestjs, roles

I'm new to nestJs and I needed to add role based access to the application so I followed the documentation but in the execution context user doesn't exist. I can't seems to find the problem here's the github repo if you need to seem more code: https://github.com/anjula-sack/slinc-backend

**roles.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ROLES_KEY } from 'src/decorators/roles.decorator';
import Role from 'src/util/enums/role.enum';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const requiredRoles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<Role[]>(ROLES_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);
    if (!requiredRoles) {
      return true;
    }
    const { user } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    console.log(context.switchToHttp().getRequest().req);

    return requiredRoles.some((role) => user.type === role);
  }
}
```

**app.controller.ts**

```
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, RolesGuard)
  @Get('me/business')
  @Roles(Role.ADMIN)
  getBusiness(@Request() req) {
    return this.usersService.getUserBusiness(req.user.id);
  }
```

Comment: Do you have the `RolesGuard` bound globally by chance?

Comment: yeah it's in the app.module.ts

Comment: Could you share the documentation you followed? Also, could you explain how you send the `user` in the request? Is it inside the header or the body? I tried the github URL you posted, but I guess it is a private repository so I can't see

Comment: can you check now? I made it public @ErangaHeshan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the code, I think you are mixing global and local guard

In `app.module.ts`, the below code is for registering global guard.
and `app.useGlobalGuard()` should be used together if you want to apply guard globally.

```
// Remove the following code in app.module.ts
{
    provide: APP_GUARD,
    useClass: RolesGuard,
}
```

But your intention should be building a **local role guard**, so please **remove the above code** and the request user will work.

Comment: what if I want to use role guard as global? I don't wanna mention it in every controller.

Comment: I removed it from app.module.ts and placed in auth.module.ts. Now, It is working fine.